# Landing page validation in protractor

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, pageobjects

I have a website with user login(https). When I do validation for each landing page when navigating from the home page, there is a page load function checks both the elements in the page and the landing page URL.
Since it is a user based page, the URL is often dynamic, and it sends out the encrypted values after the page title (*https://website/pageTitle/dynamicEncryptedValue*).

As I follow the page object model for testings, I have to mention the URL in every landing page. 
Any idea how I can keep the URL a dynamic value and validate irrespective of the user detail.

Comment: Please provide relecant code what you currently have and what you would like to have.

Comment: Consider checking the page title instead, unless of course they all have the same title.  Checking a URL for anything other than begins-with or contains is fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `website` `pageTitle` are constant and only the `dynamicEncryptedValue` will be dynamic. Hope the below way of validation helps you

`expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('https://website/pageTitle/')`

The above code validates only the constant values and omits the dynamic value in the URL.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Thanks @madhan, this is something feasible to do in a before method, before I check the url in the actual page.js